# Module 'anyModule' is not available angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, karma-jasmine

So I've been trying to inject some external modules into my app, but it seems no matter what I do I am getting the error:

"Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ui-bootstrap' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument."

in my Karma log.

So far I have tried ensuring it is included in karma.conf, and even changed around the order of requiring:

```
    files : [
  'app/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'app/components/**/*.js',
  'app/js/app.js',
  'app/js/services.js',
  'app/js/controllers.js',
  'test/unit-tests/*.js'
],
```

ensuring it's within the html:

```
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/services.js"></script>
```

I had the same error when trying to use ngResource and checked for spelling everywhere. Yet I keep getting the same error, I have searched through dozens of questions on this site but can't seem to work it out. Would be grateful if someone could point out what I may have overlooked.

My app.js file:

```
'use strict'

    var shopApp = angular.module('shopApp', [
        'ngRoute', 
        'shopServices', 
        'shopControllers', 
        'ui-bootstrap'])
```

Answer (score 1):

If I remember right, the module name for ui bootstrap is `ui.bootstrap` not `ui-bootstrap`.

Comment: how do you look up these names?

Comment: @compguy24 Mostly in the module's documentation or by looking at the `angular.module` line in the source code